# continuous function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a continuous function 
$f: \mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, $f(\mathbb{R}^2)=[0,1]$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ is bounded for all $x\in [0,1]$.
We had one idea $$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{e^{|x|+|y|}},$$ but there are some problems with zero. And there are some suspicious about existence of this function...
and the other question with additional assumption that $f(x,y)$ is monotoniс, that is the preimage of all connected set is connected

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}\left(\{x\}\right)$?

Comment: @GitGud, that is usually denoted $f^{-1}(x)$, too.

Comment: @Vasili You talk about $f$ being monotonic, do you mind defining this?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Awful notation, to be honest.

Comment: And what do you mean by "the preimage of all sets is monotonic"?

Comment: monotonic means that the preimage of connected set is connected..

Comment: Can you please add that definition to the question itself?

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this (hint form):

- Solve the problem with $\mathbb{R}^2$ replaced by $\mathbb{R}$.
- Use "distance from the origin" to define a useful function $g : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.
- Take a composition.

Answer (score 4):

Consider, for example, $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{1+x^2+y^2}$. Its image is a closed inteval, and the preimage of almost all of its elements are two circles; there are two exceptions, the endpoints of the interval, whose pre-image is just one circle.

Where did I get this from? I found a function $\phi:[0,+\infty)\to\mathbb R$ whose image is a closed interval and such that the preimages of each of the points of that interval is finite. One simple choice is $\phi(t)=\frac{t}{1+t^2}$, whose plot is

[image]

Now I considered the function $f(x,y)=\phi(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$.

Notice that knowing how I picked the function should be quite helpful in proving it has the property you want.

Comment: +1, although you spoiled my hint :(

Comment: @Mike, I did not see it, actually :(

Comment: must be multiplied by two to be completely happy :) thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, this function doesn't give an answer on second question. The answer is "no" but it's not clear why it's not so

Comment: Notice I never claimed to have answered the 2nd question! When I wrote this, I did not even know what the second question meant :-)

Comment: I understand it. It is a eternal question "does function exist?". It's easy or not easy to give an example. But proving the  non-existence is more hard. Thank you, Mariano :^) I will think